# Is it possible to do layer 2 port mirroring for family inet/inet6 interfaces in Juniper MX series routers?

Tags: juniper-junos, juniper-mx

I have connected two logical systems using logical tunnels like this:

```
[edit]
root@mx1# show logical-systems r1 interfaces lt-0/0/10 unit 10 
encapsulation ethernet;
peer-unit 80;
family inet {
    address 10.10.200.1/24;
}

[edit]
root@mx1# show logical-systems r2 interfaces lt-0/0/10 unit 80    
encapsulation ethernet;
peer-unit 10;
family inet {
    address 10.10.200.2/24;
}

[edit]
root@mx1#
```

Is it possible to do layer 2(i.e including the Ethernet header) port mirroring either for `lt-0/0/10.10` or `lt-0/0/10.80` both in ingress and egress direction?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check out https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/usage-guidelines/services-configuring-port-mirroring.html

First, set up a filter

```
filter filter-name {
  term term-name {
    then {
      port-mirror;
      accept;
    }
  }
}
```

and then

```
[edit forwarding-options port-mirroring]
input {
  maximum-packet-length bytes;
  rate rate;
  run-length number;
}
family (inet | inet6) {
  output {
    interface interface-name {
      next-hop address;
    }
    next-hop-group group-name {
      group-type (inet | inet6);
      interface interface-name {
        next-hop address;
      }
      next-hop-subgroup group-name {
        interface interface-name {
          next-hop address;
        }
      }
    }
    no-filter-check;
  }
}
```